# How to use Parcelable on non-primitive types?

Tags: android, parcelable

I have a class TableMetaAttrs:

```
public class TableMetaAttrs implements Parcelable
{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String value;
    private Tables table;
...
```

How do i implement Parcelable on *table* field? 
Class Tables also implements Parcelable.

Comment: If `Tables` implements `Parcelable`, you don't need to do anything specific to serialize/deserialize `table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the `Tables` class `implements Parcelable` as well.

That way whenever `TableMetaAttrs` is parcelling or re-building itself, it can call `putParcelable` and `getParcelable` for the table field.

**edit:**

I'm assuming Tables is a class you created, so it's signature must be

```
public class Tables implements Parcelable{
    // and somewhere in this code tables have to parcel all it's primitives
}
```

then whenever TableMetaAttrs is parcelling it's values it calls:

```
 parcel.putParcelable(table);
```

and rebuilding it:

```
  table = parcel.getParcelable();
```

Comment: If i understood you, then my constructor should look like this?
        `public TableMetaAttrs(Parcel in)
 {
  id = in.readInt();
  name = in.readString();
  value = in.readString();
  table = in.readParcelable(table.getClass().getClassLoader());
 }`

Comment: table = parcel.getParcelable(); won't work; parcel.readParcelable() might.