# Parcelable and boxed classes

Tags: android, parcelable

I've got the following class:

```
public class E implements Parcelable {
  @SerializedName("a")
  private String a= null;
  @SerializedName("b")
  private BigDecimal b= null;
  @SerializedName("c")
  private String c= null;
  @SerializedName("d")
  private String d= null;    

  protected E(Parcel in) {
   number = in.readString();
   expirationYear = in.readString();
   expirationMonth = in.readString();
  }

public static final Creator<E> CREATOR = new Creator<E>()    {
@Override
public E createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
  return new E(in);
}

  @Override
  public E[] newArray(int size) {
      return new E[size];
  }};
}
  @Override
  public int describeContents() {
     return 0;
  }

   @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
     dest.writeString(number);
     dest.writeString(expirationYear);
     dest.writeString(expirationMonth);
    }
}
```

How to parcel the data member b? Or better yet, how to parcel boxed types?

As you can see, the writeToParcel method misses the data member b as well as the protected c'tor.

Comment: `BigDecimal` is `Serializable`. `Parcel` has `writeSerializable()`.

Comment: Indeed. I forgot BigDecimal is Serializable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:
https://medium.com/the-wtf-files/the-mysterious-case-of-the-bundle-and-the-map-7b15279a794e#.sjbki9dss

[How to use Parcelable on non-primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937009/how-to-use-parcelable-on-non-primitive-types)

A good way to solve this problem (in my opinion) is to create your class extending BigDecimal and implements Parcelable interface on it.

Comment: I tested your solution and found it more elegant than using serializable directly, there you got the right answer.

Comment: This is the correct approach. `writeSerializable` internally allocates an `ObjectOutputStream` and places serialization result in Parcel via `writeByteArray`, so you may as well convert an object to byte array directly.